# html file in one subfolder, image file in another subfolder, how to img src the image file?

Tags: html

my html file is inside "drawing_html" folder.
but the image file is inside "drawing" folder.
how can I img src the image file ? what is the file path?
I tried everything, including ../ , but nothing works

[this is the screenshot of the html file and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlMEs.png)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The path seems to be correct. Maybe there are other problems like spelling of filename (capital letters?). In the screenshot there is a file IMG_1232.JPG, which has an other number and capital file extension.

Comment: the image file name is in IMG_1231.jpg, in lower case.

Comment: Maybe there are file permission problems. Can you open the image directly in a browser? Can you give us the absolute paths of the html file and the image as they are accessible from the browser?

Comment: If the HTML file is placed in the root folder, the image shows up fine. But if the HTML file is placed in the subfolder, the image doesn’t show up. I don’t know why. I tried using ../  , but it doesn’t work.